# what's the easiest way to add the value of two text fields to equal a sum to a label

Tags: ios, swift, addition

what's the easiest way to add the value of two `textField` to equal a sum to a label.
Here are the text fields and label I am using:

```
@IBOutlet weak var f1TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var f2TextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!
```

I want to add `f1TextField` with `f2TextField` and show the result in the "speedLabel".

Comment: use this code it's working for you, speedLabel.text = f1TextField.text! + f2TextField.text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the power of functional swift like this:

```
if let textField1String = textField1.text, let textField2String = textField2.text {
    let arr = [textField1String, textField2String]
    let result = arr.compactMap({ Int($0) }).reduce(0, +) //Cast in Int value + using reduce to sum all the values of array
    speedLabel.text = "\(result)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this input.  It is working as long as I don't have a decimal.  Is there an option to add if there are decimals in the problem?

Comment: You could cast in **Double** instead of *Int**: ```let result = arr.compactMap({ Double($0) }).reduce(0, +)```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you for that input.

Comment: There are better ways to add two numbers than creating and reducing an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numbers on there use this:

```
if let num1 = Double(f1TextField.text!), let num2 = Double(f2TextField.text!) {
    speedLabel.text = "\(num1 + num2)"
}
```

Comment: I think I figured where to put it, but now I'm getting "Variable used within its own initial value".

Comment: put it to button action for example

Comment: I put it into an action button and I got this:  Value of optional type 'Double?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest one is this wether it contains text or not.

```
speedLabel.text = "\(f1TextField.text)\(f2TextField.text)"
    print(speedLabel.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will execute even if one of the textfields are empty or if a number isn't inputed inside and replace the invalid fields with 0

```
speedLabel.text = "\((Double(f1TextField.text ?? "0.0") ?? 0.0) + (Double(f2TextField.text ?? "0.0") ?? 0.0))"
```